# compare to_char with float

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to compare Hour and min from dual with actual data saved in my tables .

the TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH.MI')  returns char but my data contains float number

but it says no data found .

I'm trying to do this :

```
 create or replace function getSysTime

   return char

  is
      hhhh             intervals.interval_end%type;
   v_interval_start    intervals.interval_start%type;
   v_interval_end     intervals.interval_end%type;
   v_interval_id    intervals.interval_id%type;

  begin

     select  INTERVAL_START ,INTERVAL_END , INTERVAL_ID , TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH.MI')
     into  v_interval_start , v_interval_end , v_interval_id , hhhh
    from INTERVALS

    where hhhh  =  INTERVAL_START ;

    return v_interval_id;    

   end;
```

solved with :

```
 sloved by using cast char to float . 

  where cast (TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH.MI') as float)  between  INTERVAL_START and INTERVAL_END ;
```

Comment: Do you have a column `hhhh` inside table `INTERVALS`?  What is the result of `select  INTERVAL_START ,INTERVAL_END , INTERVAL_ID , TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH.MI')
    from INTERVALS

    where hhhh  =  INTERVAL_START ;`?

Comment: hhhh is not column it's variable has type float , and TO_CHAR returns char , so when comparing char with float it returns no data found .

Comment: yes, it'll raise "no data found" , because you didn't yet set value for the `hhhh` in your where part.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. HH.MI may look like a decimal number but it isn't. MI evaluates to a number between 00 and 59 - so, for example, 0.5 means "50 minutes", not "half an hour".

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your `WHERE` clause is usually used to limit your `SELECT` statement to rows that satisfy the WHERE condition (i.e. `WHERE myTable.favoriteNumber = 5`).  Alternatively, you can have a boolean expression in there.  `WHERE 1=1` evaluates to `WHERE TRUE`.  Because it's `TRUE`, all rows are returned.  `WHERE 0=2` evalutes to `WHERE FALSE` and therefore no rows are returned, because 0 does not equal 2 in any row.

In any case, think about it logically.  In order for you to get a set of rows, you need to give it parameters.  How does the database know which rows you want?  First you have to select the fields using `SELECT`.  Which table?  Define `FROM`.  Do you want a subset of rows that meet certain conditions?  Add a `WHERE`.  Where can I store the values from the row?  Add an `INTO`.  Just because PL/SQL is procedural doesn't mean you always read top to bottom, left to right.

Your code could not have possibly inserted a value into `hhhh` before it knew which rows meet your `WHERE` condition.  Therefore, you have `WHERE null = INTERVAL_START`.

If this answer helped answer your question, please choose Accepted Answer checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for something like this ?

```
-- I'm lazy and provide only a few intervals
create table intervals as
select 1 as id, 8 +  0/60 as start_, 8 + 19/60 as end_, '8:00 - 8:19' as desc_ from dual union all
select 2 as id, 8 + 20/60 as start_, 8 + 39/60 as end_, '8:20 - 8:39' as desc_ from dual union all
select 3 as id, 8 + 40/60 as start_, 8 + 59/60 as end_, '8:40 - 8:59' as desc_ from dual union all
select 4 as id, 9 +  0/60 as start_, 9 + 19/60 as end_, '9:00 - 9:19' as desc_ from dual union all
select 5 as id, 9 + 20/60 as start_, 9 + 39/60 as end_, '9:20 - 9:39' as desc_ from dual union all
select 6 as id, 9 + 40/60 as start_, 9 + 59/60 as end_, '9:40 - 9:59' as desc_ from dual
;
```

**Example queries:**

```
select * from intervals 
where extract(hour from localtimestamp) + 
      (extract(minute from localtimestamp) / 60)
between start_ and end_;

select * from intervals
where extract(hour from to_timestamp('2013-08-29 08:39:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) + 
      (extract(minute from to_timestamp('2013-08-29 08:39:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) / 60)
between start_ and end_;

select * from intervals
where extract(hour from to_timestamp('2013-08-29 08:40:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) + 
      (extract(minute from to_timestamp('2013-08-29 08:40:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) / 60)
between start_ and end_;
```

**A convenience function to access the interval table:**

```
create or replace function get_interval_id(
  p_time in timestamp default localtimestamp
) return number as
  v_id number;
begin
  select id into v_id
    from intervals
   where extract(hour from p_time) + 
         (extract(minute from p_time) / 60)
  between start_ and end_;

  return v_id;
exception
  when others then
    return null;
end;
/
show errors
```

**How to use the function:**

```
SQL> select localtimestamp from dual;

LOCALTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-08-29 09:41:51.388

SQL> select * from intervals where id = get_interval_id;

        ID     START_       END_ DESC_
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         6 9.66666667 9.98333333 9:40 - 9:59

SQL> select * from intervals where id = get_interval_id(to_timestamp('2013-08-29 08:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

        ID     START_       END_ DESC_
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         3 8.66666667 8.98333333 8:40 - 8:59
```